# Probability brain teaser

Tags: probability

In a repeatable bet, the odds of winning a dollar are 51% (odds of losing are 49%). If you start with $100, what is the chance you will eventually go broke?

-This is the only information given.

Comment: We have $100. The house has infinite money

Comment: Is the bet offer unlimited? It means that we can offer how much money we want?

Comment: You can offer 1 dollar at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the 51% and 49% are *probabilities*.  The *odds* of winning a dollar are $\frac{51}{49}$ and the odd of losing are $\frac{49}{51}$.

There is an expression (I think originally found by Huygens) that if the player starts with $a$ dollars and the bank with $b$ dollars, and the odds of the bank winning one game is $d$, then the probability player reaches zero before the player reduces the bank to zero  is $$\frac{\,\, d^{a+b} - d^{a}}{d^{a+b}-1} \text{ or equivalently } \frac{ d^{a}-d^{a+b}\,\,}{1 - d^{a+b}} .$$  If $d \gt 1$ as in most gambling games, then as $b$ increases without limit this tends to $1$ , but if $d \lt 1$ as here, then as $b$ increases without limit this tends to $d^a$, which in this case is  $$\left(\tfrac{49}{51}\right)^{100} \approx 1.83\%.$$

The Wikipedia article on the [gambler's ruin and unfair coin flipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping) has more detail.

Comment: Great answer, but you I think you should edit the answer, because the answer should be $\left(\frac{49}{51}\right)^{100}$, because OP is interested in chance you will go broke, not the bank.

Comment: @Stefan4024 - you are correct, so I have reversed the answer